# Save an array as a string or use multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design

I am new to database design and I am using php and laravel in particular with mysql as my db layer.

I want to allow people to create and save training programs. each program can have multiple weeks, each week has 7 days, each day can have many training sessions, each session has 3 phases and each phase has many excersises.

I have a table of excersises already and I initially thought that I should just build an array of the data and store that array, unfortunately mysql does not support arrays so it would have to be stored as a string in the programs table.  Now i am thinking that maybe a table for each object(weeks, days, session) that are all related in some way to the programs table might be a better way to go.

in the near future I would like for people to be able to mark each excersise /session /day / week as completed so which solution might make that easier?

If the array is the best option should I switch to postgres from mysql for their array functionality or is saving it as a string accepted practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my view it is good to use multiple tables instead of storing array as a string.

- think of your needs
- Plan your database design in such a way that in future if you want to add some table or columns in your table you face no difficulties. also i advice you to normalize your database. here are some good links on normalization of database.
  [Normalization of database](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php),[Four ways to normalize your database](http://searchbusinessintelligence.techtarget.in/tutorial/Database-normalization-in-MySQL-Four-quick-and-easy-steps)

Answer (score 1):

It is good practise to use different tables for each one like weeks, days, sessions, phases, exercises.As per your needs you can consider another option like Mongo DB.